# Text field wont update when data pulled from xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, jquery-selectors

ok, i have a select dropdown and beneeath it is  a text field. If I poplate a static text field and onclick of its option i want to fill in the text field with the values selected in select dropdown. It works fine.
here is a

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kPC7M/)

Now  I am pulling the select dropdown options ffrom the xml and when I again use it to update my text field on click of its option, it doesn't work;

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S2qud/6/)

i know that in the second demo, the xml is not at the correct place, but I have tested this on my local machine and it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: i don't know who down voted this and for what reason, they should have mentioned it in a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're actually using multiple selects. If so, just bind the handler to the `select` element instead:

```
$(".generalTemplate").click(function() {
    var su = $(this).find(':selected').text();
    $("#sub").val(su);
});
```

This finds the selected element when clicked, and doesn't need to be bound to the individual `option` elements after they're inserted.

If you're not using a multiple, you'd want to bind to the `change` event.

```
$(".generalTemplate").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).find(':selected');
    if( selected.index() > 0 ) {
        var su = selected.text();
        $("#sub").val(su);
    }
});
```

Ultimately, what was happening was that the *asynchronous* AJAX call was executing its callback function ***after*** you ran the code to bind the handlers.

In other words, code doesn't wait for the AJAX response to arrive before it executes. By binding to the `select` itself, you know it is already available in the document, so there's no synchronization issues.

Comment: In addition, if you *do* need to bind to elements that are created asynchronously, look at using .live: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: thanks, but i don't think click and change will have  a profound difference here, i tried both and they work.

Comment: @Mike: Whatever. Do you understand the point of the answer? Bind to the select element and not the option elements, and you'll have no more synchronization issue. I still think you'll need `change`, but if you think `click` will work, then use it. But if/when it doesn't, use `change` instead.

Comment: Can i excuse the first option in the html that I am writing in using jquery. It doesn't come from xml. It is like a default place which says something like "loading options"

Comment: @Mike: I updated to test the selected element to see make sure it isn't the first.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$(".generalTemplate >option").live("click",function() {


                    var su = $(this).text();
                    $("#sub").val(su);
                });
```

Comment: why is live different than other options